# Continuous(Progressive) module in Old English

Tags: etymology, tenses, history, old-english

I'm curious as to the origins of the Continuous(progressive) module.
Whenever I meet texts emulating old speech, like in: video game RPGs,  books like the Saxon Chronicles, Hollywood movies about the middle ages, etc.,
I always feel that One of the more obvious differences is that they mostly talk with the Simple Tenses.
Now, most of the languages i know (3 more, fluently) have no Continuous module, and it got me to thinking whether Old English had it from the start or that it developed with the years?

Comment: There are a few unambiguous uses of the progressive in OE, but even Shakespeare doesn't use it that often. The passive voice only arose in the 18-19th c. The history is well summarized here: http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6362-lamont.htm

Comment: Appreciate the help.
You said that the passive voice only arose in the 18-19th c., but even though English is an Indo-European language or West Germanic  don't they all derive from Latin which does have the passive voice?

Comment: @Uhtred Ragnarsson no, Indo-European languages don't derive from Latin

Comment: I meant the passive voice, progressive aspect: _A new school is being built._  Earlier: _A new school is building_. It's all in the article I linked.

Comment: What is your “Continuous(progressive) module”, please?

If that’s different from “Continuous (progressive) mode”, how is it?

If you think video game RPG are relevant in English, how? How are they worth mentioning?

When you say “the Saxon Chronicles” is that the same as *The Anglo-Saxon Chronicles* or what?
 
If Hollywood movies matter here, how many can you cite? Which will you name?

When most of the languages you know - which three, please? - have no Continuous module, is that what English would call a mode, or what?

Mode or module, how could it matter?